# Removing redis key in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis

Deleting a key from redis using this code.

```
const { queue } = job as unknown as Job;
const jobName = '"' + (queue as unknown as any).keyPrefix + ':' + queue.name + ':' + job.id + '"';
MtPromotionProcessor.loggerService.info(`Removing ${jobName} key from redis`);
redisClient.del(jobName);
```

Even I can see in the logs the key name:

```
 Removing "bull:mt-queue:4" key from redis
```

But I still see the value in the redis:

[image]

When I remove it using `redis-cli del "bull:mt-queue:4"`, it removes it but I can't do it via code.

Comment: `redis.del` returns a promise I believe, if you add a `.then` and `.catch` and log the parameters they are getting passed, do you see any new info?

Comment: If the given code is all the code, that might actually be the issue, the `.del` might not have run by the time nodejs exits, which will be right after that statement. In that case you would have to use `await`, i,e `await redisClient.del(jobName);`